# Livewire Event Listener in JavaScript Won't Stop Executing

Tags: javascript, laravel, events, laravel-livewire

I want to listen to an event emitted by livewire in JavaScript and perform some action. JavaScript did listen to the livewire event but it won't stop executing. Ideally, it should only execute once for every event emitted. This is my Laravel livewire component:

```
    protected $listeners = [
        'reportFilterUpdated' => 'reportFilterUpdated',
        'eventListened' => 'eventListened',
    ];

    public function render()
    {
        $this->generateChartData();
        return view('dashboard');
    }

    public function generateChartData()
    {
        // Some other non-related codes
        $this->emit('reportFilterUpdated');
    }
```

And this is my JavaScript:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

    Livewire.on('reportFilterUpdated', _ => {
        console.log('event listened');
    });
    
});
```

Result in browser's console (clearly, the function wont stop executing):

> dashboard.js: (97) event listened

Any ideas on how to make it execute only once for every event emitted?

I am expecting 'event listened' to only be printed once on the console. The number of times printed should be dependent on the number of times the event is emitted from my component. 1 emission = 1 console log. Hope somebody can help, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

In Livewire, every time a change is made, the component itself is rerendered. Even a form change or a button click.

And the `render()` function will be called every single time.

In your case, every time a change is made you have
`$this->generateChartData();` being called in your `render()` function. So every time the component changes, the render function will be called and runs the `generateChartData()` function which has the emit inside of it.

So every time a change is being made, the `render()` will call `$this->generateChartData();` and every single time it will emit the event and the JavaScript will listen to it.

Its generally a good habit to leave the render function the way it is.

If you only want it to be run once, then use the `mount()` function, which will only run ONCE when the component ITSELF is rendered.

Here is a snippet from the Livewire Docs on the `mount()` function:

[image]